# Chance of rolling two dices and throwing 1 and 2 7 times in a row

Tags: probability, dice

I've just seen an episode of Red Dwarf and there was something that doesn't stop bugging me.

They played a game with $2$ dice and one of them didn't want to roll a $1$ on one dice and $$2 on the other one. 
He rolled a combination of $1$ and $2$, $7$ times in a row.
The calculation in that show was around $\frac{1}{62000000}$. How would you calculate that? 
I know just some basic stuff from school so I believe there is a $1$ in $36$ chance to get $1$ and $2$ when rolling two dices once ($36$ possible outcomes and only one correct), but I can't wrap my head around how to calculate multiple throws. Thank you. :)

Comment: It is exactly: $612220031:1.$ $612220032=18^7,$ and in any roll of $2$ dice, the probability  of a $1$ and $2$ is $1/18.$

Comment: Are the dice different (either in color, shape, size, or time of throw), or are they indistinguishable (look exactly the same and thrown simultaneously)?

Comment: They are exactly the same and they are thrown simultaneously. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 36 possible outcomes when throwing two dices, as there are 6 outcomes throwing only one dice. But, naming a dice $A$ and the other $B$, there are two outcomes you are looking for; $A=1$, $B=2$ and $A=2$, $B=1$.

So the probability of getting 1 and 2 by throwing two dices is
$$
\frac{2}{36}=\frac{1}{18}.
$$
Then, to get 1 and 2 seven times in a row,
$$
\left(\frac{1}{18}\right)^7=\frac{1}{612220032}\cong1.63\cdot10^{-9}.
$$
So the rate would be $612220032:1$. Still, this is 10 times bigger than the one you said of 62 million. I searched on the internet about this episode and I found a quote in [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5218254/characters/nm0057368), saying exactly what you said. I really believe that the show is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for such a good answer. You explained the math well and also you've found the origin of this confusion. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score -1):

The chance of rolling a dice with a specific sequence (ANY sequence really) with length $n$ (in this case, $14$) is $\left(\dfrac{1}{6}\right)^n$

So calculating $\left(\dfrac{1}{6}\right)^{14}$, we get $\dfrac{1}{78364164096}$

I have no clue why they came up with $1$ in $62$ million chance. The show might've made a mistake.

Comment: As has been mentioned in several comments, the two dice are indistinguishable, so we can't differentiate between the result 1-2 and the result 2-1 when we throw the two dice once. As a consequence, we have to account for either of those results happening on each throw of the two dice. You have just calculated the probability of the exact sequence 1-2-1-2-1-2-1-2-1-2-1-2-1-2, but there are loads of other sequences that would be just as valid.